How to set the page scaling percentage using Ctrl+scroll wheel after maximizing page size in Python Playwright?
How to set the page scaling percentage using Ctrl+scroll wheel after maximizing page size in Python playwright？？？

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
